# How to make a working NavBar in React-Boostrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm working in a web react application for the first time. I'm trying to implement a `NavBar` but I have a little trouble when implementing the functionality, this is what I've got so far (Im using REFLUX for the communication between components):

```
 getInitialState: function() {
               return {
                 hide:[false,true],
               }
             },
             navegar: function(item){
                var tmp =[];
                for (var i = 0; i < this.state.hide.length; i++) {
                    if (i == (item-1)){
                        tmp[i] = false; 
                    }else{
                        tmp[i] = true; 
                    }
                }

                this.setState({hide:tmp});
             },

             render: function() {
       return (
         <div>
          <NavBarComponent onClick={this.navegar}/>
          <ViewComponent1 className={this.state.hide[0] ? 'hidden' : ''}/>
          <ViewComponent2 className={this.state.hide[1] ? 'hidden' : ''}/>


        </div>
        );
    }

var NavBarComponent = React.createClass({
                handleSelect: function(selectedKey) {
                    this.props.onClick(selectedKey);
                },
                render: function() {
                 return (
                    <div>          
                        <Navbar fluid activeKey={1} >             
                            <Navbar.Header>
                                <Navbar.Brand>
                                    <NavItem eventKey={1} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>TITLE</NavItem>
                                        </Navbar.Brand>
                                        <Navbar.Toggle />                    
                            </Navbar.Header>
                            <Navbar.Collapse>
                                <Nav navbar onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                                    <NavItem eventKey={2}>First Tab</NavItem>
                                    <NavItem eventKey={3}>Second Tab</NavItem>
                                    <NavItem eventKey={4}>Dietas Compartidas</NavItem>           
                                    //Etc.....
                                    </Nav>
                                </Navbar.Collapse>              
                        </Navbar>            
                    </div>);
                }
            });
```

The thing is that this method works only with two views (two `NavBar` menu options) but I don't know how to implement my `navBar` with multiple options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I want to recommend using a routing library like [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) instead of hiding and showing views with css if this is your main navigation. The main strength is that it makes it much easier to handle urls and internal links. So with a routing library you could just use links directly in the Bootstrap NavItems to route through your app.

However, I understand if you don't need a complex routing library so I continued the work you started but with a some changes

- Since you wanted to be flexible on the number of views and options available in the nav bar I think the best approach is to use Ids. This is just an opinion but to me it feels like a more clean approach since it adds readability. So I replaced the `hide` array in the `Container`'s state with an `activeViewId` state, this also let me remove your `navegar` which made the code simpler.
- Instead of having to update both the `Container` and the `NavBarComponent` when adding a new view and a navigation option, I prefer to keep all that logic in one place. In this case the logic is in the `Container`. So if you want to add a new view, update the `navOptions` and match those `viewId`s with the ids on which you trigger `hide`.

Below you have a working example where you can add as many views and NavOptions as you want to just by updating the `Container` component.

Let me know if you have any questions regarding the answer!

```js
const RB = ReactBootstrap;
const Navbar = RB.Navbar;
const NavItem = RB.NavItem;
const Nav = RB.Nav;

var Container = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      activeViewId: "mainView"
    }
  },

  navegar: function(id){
    this.setState({
      activeViewId: id
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    const navOptions = [
      {title: "BRAND TITLE", viewId: "mainView"},
      {title: "First tab", viewId: "first-tab-view"},
      {title: "Second tab", viewId: "second-tab-view"},
      {title: "Dietas Compartidas", viewId: "spanish-tab-view"}
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <NavBarComponent onClick={this.navegar} options={navOptions}>
          <div className={this.state.activeViewId !== "mainView" ? 'hidden' : ''}>View 1</div>
          <div className={this.state.activeViewId !== "first-tab-view" ? 'hidden' : ''}>View 2</div>
          <div className={this.state.activeViewId !== "second-tab-view" ? 'hidden' : ''}>View 3</div>
          <div className={this.state.activeViewId !== "spanish-tab-view" ? 'hidden' : ''}>View 4</div>
        </NavBarComponent>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var NavBarComponent = React.createClass({
  handleSelect: function(selectedKey) {
    this.props.onClick(selectedKey);
  },
  
  defaultProps: {
    // fallback
    options: [
      {title: "BRAND TITLE", viewId: "mainView"}
    ]
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar fluid activeKey={this.props.options[0].viewId} >
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <NavItem eventKey={this.props.options[0].viewId} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                {this.props.options[0].title}
              </NavItem>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />                    
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
              <Nav navbar onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                {this.props.options.map((option, n) => {
                  if (n === 0) {return null;}
                  return <NavItem key={option.viewId} eventKey={option.viewId}>{option.title}</NavItem>
                })}
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>              
        </Navbar>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Container/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.30.7/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<div id="app"></div>
```